# Error trying to add bulk users into active directory using batch

Tags: batch-file, active-directory

I'm using a simple Microsoft DOS batch script in Windows Server 2012 to add users into Active Directory; however, I'm getting errors

> "delim=," was unexpected at this time

csv file

```
smith,john
page,jimmy
cooke,pane
doe,jane
```

DOS for loop

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delim=," %%a in (C:\users.csv) do (
    set username=%%b:~0,1%%a
    dsadd user "cn=%username%,cn=users,dc=contoso,dc=com" -fn %%b -ln %%a -upn username@contoso.com -pwd Password123 
)
```

Comment: ok I just remove "delim" and I got pass that error; however, I'm having problems extracting first char from firstname or %%b variable and creating username in the form of jsmith... any suggestions?

Comment: You may using powershell instead of msdos shell.

Answer (score 0):

Next commented code snippet could help:

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=, " %%a in (C:\users.csv) do (
    rem                 ^  ^
    set "username=%%b"
    rem e.g.      john
    set "username=!username:~0,1!%%a"
    rem e.g.                    jsmith
    dsadd user "cn=!username!,cn=users,dc=contoso,dc=com" -fn %%b -ln %%a -upn !username!@contoso.com -pwd Password123 
    rem                                                                        ^        ^
)
```

However, for debugging purposes, use `echo dsadd user` instead of operational `dsadd user` command as follows:

```
echo dsadd user "cn=!username!,cn=users,dc=contoso,dc=com" -fn %%b -ln %%a -upn !username!@contoso.com -pwd Password123
```

Remove `echo` no sooner than debugged. **Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`!username!` special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- (`!username:~0,1!`) [Extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)